# No internet at all with Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: internet, 16.04, ethernet

For the first time I am really struggling with this version of Ubuntu.

The installation runs perfectly, and even downloads missing files/packets during the setup via my ethernet cable.

Then when I arrive on my fresh new desktop, I have no connection at all. No wifi working (I was expecting that with my BCM4311) and no ethernet.
No problems with my internet provider or other computers : my ethernet cable is recognized in the installation and also in the live version !

Do you also have problems with network setup with Xenial Xerus ?

Here is the hardware :

```
  lspci -knn | grep Net -A2

0c:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN [14e4:4311] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Dell Wireless 1390 WLAN Mini-Card [1028:0007]
    Kernel driver in use: wl
```

And

```
lspci | egrep -i 'network|ethernet'

03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4401-B0 100Base-TX (rev 02)
0c:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Corporation BCM4311 802.11b/g WLAN (rev 01
```

Thank you very much !

Comment: Please add the output of`lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` and `lspci | egrep -i 'network|ethernet'`

Answer (score 2):

I finally solved my issue. I went with the sudo nautilus in

```
etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-bcm43.conf
```

And then I deleted some lines of drivers that were blacklisted. In my case I removed the b43, b43firmware and b44. One reboot later, I got my wired connection back.
But still don't know why bcmwl blacklisted these drivers ...